# Getting HTML elements by their attribute names

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There are methods available in JavaScript to get HTML elements using their ID, Class and Tag.

```
document.getElementByID(*id*);
document.getElementsByClassName(*class*);
document.getElementsByTagName(*tag*);
```

Is there any method available to get the elements according to the attribute name.

EX:

```
<span property="v:name">Basil Grilled Tomatoes and Onions</span>
```

Like:

```
document.getElementsByAttributeName("property");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to do it this way specifically? It's very inefficient and there are better ways of approaching it.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Yes, the function is `querySelectorAll` (or `querySelector` for a single element), which allows you to use CSS selectors to find elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[property]'); // All with attribute named "property"
document.querySelectorAll('[property="value"]'); // All with "property" set to "value" exactly.
```

[(Complete list of attribute selectors on MDN.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

This finds all elements with the attribute property. It would be better to specify a tag name if possible:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[property]');
```

You can work around this if necessary by looping through all the elements on the page to see whether they have the attribute set:

```
var withProperty = [],
    els = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), // or '*' for all types of element
    i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].hasAttribute('property')) {
        withProperty.push(els[i]);
    }
}
```

Libraries such as jQuery handle this for you; it's probably a good idea to let them do the heavy lifting.

For anyone dealing with ancient browsers, note that `querySelectorAll` was introduced to Internet Explorer in v8 (2009) and fully supported in IE9. All [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll) support it.

Comment: I believe you'll need double quotes around the attribute value.
document.querySelectorAll('[property=value]'); should be document.querySelectorAll('[property="value"]');

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume that you have an input:

```
         <input type='text' name='from'/>
```

then you can access it as follow:

```
        document.querySelector('input[name="from"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `querySelectorAll`:

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('span[property=name]');
```

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery this is so:

```
$("span['property'=v:name]"); // for selecting your span element
```

Comment: He's using vanilla Javascript, so he's probably not trying to use jQuery in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

Just another answer

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    function(el) {return el.getAttribute('property') == 'v.name';}
);
```

In future

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    (el) => el.getAttribute('property') == 'v.name'
)
```

#### 3rd party edit

Intro

- The [call() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.
- The [filter() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Given this html markup

```
<span property="a">apple - no match</span>
<span property="v:name">onion - match</span>
<span property="b">root - match</span>
<span property="v:name">tomato - match</span>
<br />
<button onclick="findSpan()">find span</button>
```

you can use this javascript

```
function findSpan(){

    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var spansV = Array.prototype.filter.call(
         spans,
         function(el) {return el.getAttribute('property') == 'v:name';}
    );
    return spansV;
}
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/XWXbero)

Comment: How would the function be used / called?

Comment: You can call as I wrote, just assign the result to a variable. However, 5 years later, I think @paula-fleck answer would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) since that Javascript library provides a lot of functionality you might want to use in this kind of cases. In your case you could write (or find one on the internet) a hasAttribute method, like so (not tested):

```
$.fn.hasAttribute = function(tagName, attrName){
  var result = [];
  $.each($(tagName), function(index, value) { 
     var attr = $(this).attr(attrName); 
     if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false)
        result.push($(this));
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get attribute using javascript,

```
element.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

Ex:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var myattr = wrap.getAttribute("title");
```

Refer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Answer (score -1):

With **prototypejs** :

```
 $$('span[property=v.name]');
```

or

```
document.body.select('span[property=v.name]');
```

**Both** return an **array**