# How to count the number of radio button groups (by name attribute)?

Tags: javascript, dom

There are three single selections on document.

```
<input  type="radio" name="delete1">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete1">no<input  type="radio" name="delete1">all
<input  type="radio" name="delete2">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete2">no
<input  type="radio" name="delete3">yes<input  type="radio" name="delete3">no
```

There are 7 elements with `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`.

It is 3 groups for people to select,every group can select 1 input.

I want to get the number of groups not the number of input tags in each groups.

Comment: What do you mean *select it into 3*?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the current selection from each of the three radio button groups? To start with each input should have a `value` attribute unique within its group.

Comment: It is 3 groups for people to select,every group can select 1 input.

Comment: To be a little clear... you have 3 groups of input tag. each group contains three input tags and you want the user to have the option to select only one in each group?....

Comment: No,the first one contain 3 input tags ,the other two contains 2 input tags.

Comment: So you want to select what from which group?

Comment: it is no use to write it as `document.getElementsByTagName('input')/2` or  `document.getElementsByTagName('input')/3`

Comment: I want to get the group numbers :3 .

Comment: You mean like the number of input tags in each groups?

Comment: I think OP means to get the number of groups

Comment: @Phil thanks..I figured it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
groups = {};
var all_input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < all_input.length; ++i) {
  if (!(all_input[i].name in groups)) {
    groups[all_input[i].name] = 0;
  } else {
    groups[all_input[i].name] += 1;
  }


}
var message = Object.keys(groups).length;
console.log(message);
alert(message)
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="delete1">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete1">no
<input type="radio" name="delete1">all
<input type="radio" name="delete2">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete2">no
<input type="radio" name="delete3">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete3">no
```

Comment: If the sole purpose is to count the groups, couldn't you replace the if/else with just `groups[all_input[i].name] = true` and then use `Object.keys(groups).length`? (If you also want to count the number of radios in each group then the `if` case should be `= 1`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to count the number of unique `name` attributes like this

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name]'),
  inputsByName = Array.prototype.reduce.call(inputs, function(map, input) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, input.name)) {
      map[input.name] = [input];
    } else {
      map[input.name].push(input);
    }
    return map;
  }, Object.create(null));

console.log('Inputs by name: ', inputsByName);
console.log('Unique radio input group count =',
    Object.keys(inputsByName).length);
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="delete1" value="yes">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete1" value="no">no
<input type="radio" name="delete1" value="all">all
<input type="radio" name="delete2" value="yes">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete2" value="no">no
<input type="radio" name="delete3" value="yes">yes
<input type="radio" name="delete3" value="no">no
```

This has the added bonus of providing you with a map of all the radio button elements by name.

Comment: @repzero I don't really care about the points but I do like to know why somebody thinks this answer is not useful. Thanks all the same

Comment: Yes..That's what I get angry with: when you try to help by taking your time and effort so that some perfectionist or malicious person is pulling the straw out of your eyes instead of theirs....

Answer (score 1):

[ES6 Set.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

`.getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection` which behaves similar to an array so that `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]` references the 3rd input element in the DOM.

If you want to count the unique number of radio input groups (those with same `name` attribute) simply get the `HTMLCollection` of all radio inputs then loop over them.  Inside the loop, if the name is new `.push` that name to an array called `groups` and finally a `numberOfGroups.length` should give you your number.

```js
var doc = document;
var inputs = doc.getElementsByTagName('input');
var groups = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  groups.push(inputs[i].name)
}

console.log(Array.from(new Set(groups)));
console.log(Array.from(new Set(groups)).length);
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="fruit">apple</input>
<input type="radio" name="fruit">orange</input>
<input type="radio" name="fruit">grape</input>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="vegetable">lettuce</input>
<input type="radio" name="vegetable">tomato</input>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="seasoning">salt</input>
<input type="radio" name="seasoning">pepper</input>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question

Comment: I believe the question has been edited.  To get the number of radio inputs per name just see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647095/getting-html-elements-by-their-attribute-names).  It's been answered several years ago.

Comment: I edited the title to match the rest of the question but that's about it. I don't see how that other question is the same either

Comment: That better?  .Set

Comment: Very nice :) You should also be able to use `new Set(groups).size` instead of creating a new array just for the length.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var b = [a.delete1,a.delete2,a.delete3];
```