# Getting HTML elements using applescript

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

Warning: I'm not good at JavaScript, I based the JavaScript part off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647095/getting-html-elements-by-their-attribute-names).

So I have a little Script that should set `theDuration` to an HTML element in the front window of active tab. I looked at the HTML and the Element in full is `<span id="duration">00:10:00</span>`. I want `theDuration` to be `00:10:00`. I know you can set JavaScript variables to the JavaScript code below since it's mentioned in the [post I based it off of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647095/getting-html-elements-by-their-attribute-names), but when I try to run the code down below, it doesn't work.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window to set theDuration to execute javascript "document.getElementById('duration');"
end tell
```

EDIT: Now that I placed the `tell active tab of front window` in front of the `set theDuration to...`, it compiles, but theDuration is just `{}` instead of `00:10:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following **HTML** *snippet*:

```
<span id="duration">00:10:00</span>
```

And wanting the *variable* `theDuration` to contain the value of `duration` when the *element* is `id`, you would query with:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    set theDuration to ¬
        execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
            "document.getElementById('duration').innerText;"
```

---

**From:** [W<sup>3</sup>Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

### HTML DOM getElementById() Method

**Definition and Usage**

The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.

This method is one of the most common methods in the HTML DOM, and is used almost every time you want to manipulate, or get info from, an element on your document.

Returns *null* if no elements with the specified ID exists.

An ID should be unique within a page. However, if more than one element with the specified ID exists, the getElementById() method returns the first element in the source code.

**Syntax:**

```
document.getElementById(elementID)
```

**Parameter Values:**

- **Parameter**: elementID
- **Type**: String
- **Description**: Required. The ID attribute's value of the element you want to get

---

**From:** [W<sup>3</sup>Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)

### HTML DOM innerText Property

**Definition and Usage**

The innerText property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, **and all its descendants**.

If you set the innerText property, any child nodes are removed and replaced by a single Text node containing the specified string.

**Note:** This property is similar to the textContent property, however there are some differences:

- textContent returns the text content of **all** elements, while innerText returns the content of all elements, **except** for `<script>` and `<style>` elements.
- innerText will not return the text of elements that are hidden with CSS (textContent will).

**Tip:** To set or return the HTML content of an element, use the innerHTML property.

---

**From:** [W<sup>3</sup>Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

### HTML DOM innerHTML Property

**Definition and Usage**

The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

**Syntax**

Return the innerHTML property:

```
HTMLElementObject.innerHTML
```

Set the innerHTML property:

```
HTMLElementObject.innerHTML = text
```

**Property Values**

- **Value**: text
- **Description**: Specifies the HTML content of an element

---

**My Notes:**

Since you asked for a *canonical answer*, I'm quoting this information from [W<sup>3</sup>Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) as I find to be one of the best canonical sources that has help me when using **JavaScript** mixed with **AppleScript**.

Note that in this particular case, given the **HTML** *snippet*, that **HTMLElement.innerText** and **HTMLElement.innerHTML** will both return .e.g. `00:10:00`. As both can return/set the text content of the specified node, just be aware of their differences based on your particular needs/usage, and to what specifically you are applying it to.

Comment: Yes, I already figured out the difference, it's different when working with bigger chunks of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should request for **innerHTML**, and indicate the **expected result type**. Not tested, because I have not Google Chrome and your webpage:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
  tell active tab of front window to set theDuration to (execute javascript "document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML;") as text
end tell
```

Comment: JSYK... `... as text` is not necessary and is redundant in this use case because the _class_ of the _value_ of the `theDuration` _variable_ is already _text_ whether one uses **HTMLElement.innerText** or **HTMLElement.innerHTML**, as **HTML** is already _text_ to begin with.